# How to use wait() and notify() with the use of different classes in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, concurrency

I am trying to enclose a wait function in classA, but I want to `notify()` from classB. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have them share a monitor object.

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/wait-notify-and-notifyall-in-java.html

Comment: You are expected to show some research effort when posting a question like this. Where is the code you have written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options here. The simplest is created an object, of any type really, and sharing that object between the two classes.

Any object in java can has the notify() and wait() methods.

So you can create an object

```
Object sharedObject = new Object();
```

Then pass that object to both classes (or more accurately, instance of the classes)

```
ClassA a = new ClassA(sharedObject);
ClassB b = new ClassB(sharedObject);
```

Then inside some method in ClassA you can call:

```
synchronized(sharedObject) {
     sharedObject.wait();
}
```

On one thread, and then on another thread you can wake it up by calling:

```
synchronized(sharedObject) {
     sharedObject.notify();
}
```

That is a basic way of doing this.
Notice, that before waiting or notifying you need to synchronize on that object.

There's a more advanced and robust way to do it, with condition variables.

You can learn more about this in this excellent online course https://www.udemy.com/java-multithreading-concurrency-performance-optimization/?couponCode=CONCURRENCY

It's really cheap but teaches you how to use all those concurrency techniques really well.